# What is the 蜀语圣经?

Tags: topolect

Looking for old dialectical works.

Figured there should be some topolectical Bible translations in the very least.

Came across this [forum](http://www.photosharp.com.tw/FORUM/ArticleList.aspx?ForumId=40&TopicId=41385&Page=7) post:

> 小時候曾經參加過天主教會的聚會，神父或牧師在每回講經佈道前總會打開放滿各種語言文字聖經的書櫃，讓信徒挑選自己看得懂的文字聖經，記得其中至少就有國語聖經(北京話)，台語聖經(河洛話或閩南話、福佬話)，客語聖經(客家話)，粵語(廣東話)聖經，蜀語聖經(四川話)，吳語聖經(蘇州話寧波話) ，魯語聖經(山東話) 、廈門話聖經，潮州話聖經，上海話聖經，福閩語聖經(福州話)，莆仙話，甌語聖經(溫州話)。

My focus is on Sichuanese; the `蜀语圣经 (四川话)` part of the post really caught my attention.

What is the 蜀语圣经?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably refer to 四川话 of either 成都 or 重庆, and very unlikely to be the extinct [巴蜀语](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba-Shu_Chinese). However, it seems unlikely, as the Mandarin (referring to 官话 here) versions listed [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=4fWf1WlCStcC&oi=fnd&pg=PA54) do not include any form of Sichuanese; nor can I find it in the Spillet (1975) catalogue. The furthest south for Mandarin is the Nanjing Mandarin version of 1857, adapted from the Delegates' Wenli (i.e. Classical Chinese) version.

Another line of evidence is that the romanisation for Chongqing/Chengdu Sichuanese is distinctly non-missionary based. The earlier publications from a form of [Latinxua Sinwenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latinxua_Sin_Wenz) specific to southwestern Mandarin, originally developed in the Soviet Union and in use in the 1930s. The other, more current one is based on Hanyu Pinyin, and is known as [Sichuanhua Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sichuanese_Pinyin), and is mostly used in academic or learning materials. Compare this to the situation for Min varieties of Chinese, the principal romanisations for which were overwhelmingly developed by missionaries.

Of course, a non-classical / non-standard Mandarin Chinese Bible can be written in Chinese characters (compare the New Cantonese Version). But again there appears to be no record of this.

It would be of course hugely exciting if this did turn out to be true, and such a thing would not be outside the realms of possibility. With the current evidence, it seems nonetheless unlikely. Perhaps it was a non-Sinitic language of the southwest like Lisu or Hmong.

Comment: Can you find the Nanjing Mandarin version?

Comment: Here's the Nanjing Mandarin version in case anyone is interested: http://bible.fhl.net/new/ob.php?book=90&version=&page=1